# Test strings similar to "aaabbbccc"

Tags: regex, string, pcre

I need to match a string with arbitrary length, in which every character has a run of adjacent repeats of identical length.

Such as `aabb`, both of `a` and `b` repeat twice, but not `aabbc` since `c` must repeats twice as well.

Here's a chart that shows the strings I want to pass and fail:

| pass | fail |
| --- | --- |
| `a` | `abb` |
| `aa` | `aab` |
| `ab` | `xyyz` |
| `abc` | `foof` |
| `aabb` | `abcc` |
| `aabbaa` | `abbab` |
| `aabbcc` |  |
| `aaabbb` |  |
| `aaabbbccc` |  |
| `aaaabbbbcccc` |  |
| `wwxxyyzzww` |  |
| `hhiiffggeecchhdd` |  |

I'm using PCRE regex engine, it supports recursion but not unfixed length lookbehinds.

I tried something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/L5AecY/1), but it doesnt work:

```
^((.)(?:\2(?:(?!\1)(?1))*)*)$
```

Is it possible? Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

---

Btw, I don't need capture groups or matching the whole text, just fail the test if the string does not follow the rule.

---

#### Update:

Finally I came out [the following regex](https://regex101.com/r/xU5pJT/1) which works but it's rediculously long, but it shows it is possible.

```
^(?!.*(?:(?<=^)|(?<=(.)))(?=(?!\1)(.)\2*(?!\2)(.))(?:\2+(\2(?4)?\3)|(?4)\3+)(?!\3)).+$
```

> It is the [final question of the regex quiz on regex101](https://regex101.com/quiz/28), the result shows the shortest answer is 46 characters, mine is 85. Not sure how does that work but I'll take what I can get...

Comment: If there's an upper bound on the number of repeats (_i.e._ 4 in the case of your table), then you should probably split the expression into 4 different variations for a full string match.

Comment: @paddy There's no upper bound, it can repeat as many times at possible as long as the repeat lengths match.

Comment: It doesn't seem like regular expressions are a good match for this at all.  Intuitively, this seems like the kind of thing that could be handled by simply passing over the string once to determine the minimum and maximum runs of consecutive characters, and based on your examples for what constitutes failure, it would appear no further smarts are necessary -- the min and max counts of consecutive characters must be equal.

Comment: The answer is "no": regex can't do it.

Comment: Is there a limit on the size of the repeat blocks?

Comment: Note that all input passes, because if `a` passes, then the length of the blocks may be 1, and all input is a series of repeats of size 1. If `ab` passes, so should `abbab`

Comment: I'm intrigued. Would be nice to know the 46 chars solution.

Comment: I think it's possible to write about 46 symbols but why the shortest answer is more important than the fastest?

Answer (score 1):

No. It's not possible for arbitrary length repeat blocks.

There is no way to have a back reference (or similar) to a quantifier.

---

However, if the maximum length is limited, for example 4:

```
^(((.)\1))+|((.)\1{2}))+|((.)\1{3}))+)$
```

Comment: But it's possible to match [`aaabbb`](https://regex101.com/r/VwlvyG/1/), maybe there is a way

Comment: @HaoWu you can't recurse in two places simultaneously. I've been trying for an hour and the closest I can get is this: `(\w)(?R)?((?!\1)\w)` but it fails on odd terms and special case of `abcc`. Obviously the other special case is just `^(\w)\1*$` (the whole string is the same character)

Comment: @HaoWu it's not possible to match `aabb` or `aaabbb` or `aaaabbbb` when the length of repeat blocks is arbitrary

Comment: Just came across the same question and I think it is possible to do it: [`^(?=(.)\1*((?!\1).))(\1(?3)?\2)$`](https://regex101.com/r/EIbHdh/1). It uses a lookahead at the beginning to capture each character and then use a recursion to make sure all repeats are the same length.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a single regex, however it's possible with a sequence of regexes using split, filter, map & reduce.

You can do that in any language; here is a JavaScript snippet that uses your test patterns:

```js
const patterns = [
  'a',            'aa',         'ab',
  'abc',          'aabb',       'aabbaa',
  'aabbcc',       'aaabbb',     'aaabbbccc',
  'aaaabbbbcccc', 'wwxxyyzzww', 'hhiiffggeecchhdd',
  'abb',          'aab',        'xyyz',
  'foof',         'abcc',       'abbab'
];
patterns.forEach((str) => {
  let valid = str
  .split(/(?<=(.))(?!\1)/)
  .filter((v, i) => {
    return i % 2 === 0;
  })
  .map((v) => {
    return v.length;
  })
  .reduce((acc, item) => {
    if(acc === -1) {
      acc = item;
    } else if(acc && acc != item) {
      acc = 0;
    }
    return acc;
  }, -1);
  console.log(str + ' ==> ' + (valid ? true : false));
});
```

Output:

```
a ==> true
aa ==> true
ab ==> true
abc ==> true
aabb ==> true
aabbaa ==> true
aabbcc ==> true
aaabbb ==> true
aaabbbccc ==> true
aaaabbbbcccc ==> true
wwxxyyzzww ==> true
hhiiffggeecchhdd ==> true
abb ==> false
aab ==> false
xyyz ==> false
foof ==> false
abcc ==> false
abbab ==> false
```

Explanation:

- `.split(/(?<=(.))(?!\1)/)` - split the string at transitions from one letter to another using a positive lookbehind and a negative lookahead
- `.filter()` - filter out odd items from the resulting array; this is because the capture group in the positive lookbehind (needed for negative lookahead) appears in the resulting split as elements
- `.map()` - map returning the string length of each element
- `.reduce()`:

  - the accumulator is initialized as -1
  - at the first element, the accumulator is set to the item value, e.g. string length
  - from second element on, the accumulator is set to 0 if the item length does not match the accumulator value